# What is an absolute frequency reference (Frequency combs)?

Tags: frequency, experimental-technique

So I am currently studying for my bachelors thesis which is all about **frequency combs**. I am reading a lot of articles about them but I just keep coming across things that the people who wrote the articles take as something I should already know.

At the moment I am a bit unsure about the term **absolute frequency reference**.
In the article I am currently reading they write:

*"The fourth harmonic of a methane-stabilized He-Ne laser that operated with high accuracy was used as an absolute frequency reference for the femtosecond comb, which allowed us to access new targets."*

Can someone help me understand what this reference does and why it is necessary?

Comment: The frequency combs that I have used are tunable - that is usually the whole point of using one. However, you would like to know the exact frequency (or as close as possible) that you have one set at. One way is to use a well-characterized frequency (such as the 4th harmonic mentioned), and tune the comb across it, establishing an exact frequency vs tuning knob calibration. Then you proceed to perform your precision experiment. To do it properly requires a reference in the same spectral range as your experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a really good crystal oscillator for example. I can have an extremely stable oscillator, where I know that it has the same frequency today that it did last year (to within some extremely small uncertainty). But maybe I have no idea what its frequency is in Hertz, or maybe I know it only very approximately. And maybe if I built 10 such oscillators, they would all have kinda different frequencies, even though each individual frequency would be very stable.

That would be an example of a frequency reference which is not an "absolute" frequency reference.

An absolute frequency reference should be tied to some unchanging property of the physical world, like an atomic transition frequency ... ideally a frequency that someone else has previously compared to a caesium atomic clock, which in turn underlies the definition of a second. So you really know what the frequency is in Hertz, now and forever.

A crystal oscillator can become an absolute frequency reference if you calibrate it against a different absolute frequency reference. But that works only temporarily! The crystal oscillator frequency will drift over time, and you'll eventually need to calibrate it again.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Are you able to explain me how that calibration is done? Like, physically how would you do that? Would you tune the laser by for example modifying the gain madia a bit? I guess that the tuning can only be done within a pretty limited range?

Comment: I was referring to calibration for the purpose of timekeeping. Then there's no need to adjust the frequency. The only thing you need to do is measure its absolute frequency and write it down. If it's a clock with output in seconds, it probably has control software where you can say what the exact oscillator frequency is.